# Testing window.location in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to test the window functionality via jest. I have a function which appends a query param to the url and redirects the page to the other page. A rough snippet of the code is below:

```
var url = new URL(targetUrl);
    if (typeof status !== undefined) {
      // base encode status
      url.searchParams.append("status", status);
      window.location = url.toString();
```

I am new to jest and I am facing a bit of difficulty simulating the mock test for this, hence can you please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to mock windows.location. I am attaching a code snippet which will be helpful for others who are trying to mock it.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    delete window.location;
    window.location = Object.assign(new URL("https://dickssportinggoods.com"));
});

it('mocks windows.location function', () => {
    //call your function.
    expect(global.window.location).toBe("https://yoururl.com/?status=SUCCESS");
});
```